# Recursive Function Logic Problem

Tags: php, recursion

I have a recursive function with a bug that I am having trouble with.  The logic is as follows:
Forms have Fields of various types.  One type of field is a Reference Field, which links a Form to another Form.  And, References can chain.  Example:  I can have a Prescription Form with a Reference to an Encounter, that has a Reference to  Doctor that has a Reference to Person.  The same Encounter Form has a Reference to Patient That also refers to Person.

So, the Reference field chain for Doctor Last Name would look like Field 49 on Prescription refers to Encounter. Field 7 on Encounter refers to Doctor. Field 6 on Doctor refers to Person.  Field 1 on Person refers to Last Name. [49-7-6-1]

The Reference chain for Patient Last Name would be [49-5-4-1] following the same logic.

My problem is this.  With the current function, the Reference chain strings have problems if I have branching references at a lower level.  Instead of ending up with [49-5-4-1] for Patient Last Name, I get [49-7-5-4-1].

## The function is as follows:

```
function get_reference_fields($form_id, $base_fields = array(), $ref_field_id = null, $ref_string = null, $field_name = null,$base_form = null,$form_name=null) {

         if(!$base_form) {
             $base_form = $form_id;
         }
         App::import('model', 'Section');
         $zmr_sections = new Section();


         $sectionList = $zmr_sections->getSectionList($form_id);


         if ($sectionList) {

             $new_base_fields = $this->Field->find('list', array('joins' => array(
                 array(
                     'table' => 'field_types',
                     'alias' => 'Type',
                     'type' => 'left',
                     'foreignKey' => false,
                     'conditions' => array('Type.id = Field.field_type_id')
                 )), 'conditions' => array('Type.base_type != "formatting" AND Type.base_type != "reference" AND Type.base_type != "reverse reference"', 'Field.active=1', 'Field.section_id IN (' . $sectionList . ')')));


             if ($ref_field_id) {
                 $newFields = array();


                 foreach ($new_base_fields AS $key => $field) {
                     if ($field_name) {

                         $field = $form_name . ' - ' . $field;
                     }

                     $newFields[$ref_string . '-' . $key] = $field;

                 }
                 $new_base_fields = $newFields;
             }
             if (!$base_fields) {
                 $base_fields = array();
             }

             $base_fields = $base_fields + $new_base_fields;


             $reference_fields = $this->Field->find('all', array('joins' => array(
                 array(
                     'table' => 'field_types',
                     'alias' => 'Type',
                     'type' => 'left',
                     'foreignKey' => false,
                     'conditions' => array('Type.id = Field.field_type_id')
                 )), 'conditions' => array('Type.base_type' => 'reference', 'Field.active=1', 'Field.section_id IN (' . $sectionList . ')')));


             foreach ($reference_fields AS $reference_field) {

                 $field_name = $reference_field['Field']['name'];
                 $query = "SELECT form_id FROM zmr_lists WHERE id=" . $reference_field['Field']['zmr_list_id'];

                 $list_data = $this->query($query);
                 $new_form_id = $list_data[0]['zmr_lists']['form_id'];



                 if($form_id == $base_form){
                     $ref_string = $reference_field['Field']['id'];
                     $form_name = $this->Field->Section->Form->field('Form.label',array('Form.id'=>$new_form_id));

                 }else{
                     $ref_string .= '-'. $reference_field['Field']['id'];
                     $form_name .= '-'. $this->Field->Section->Form->field('Form.label',array('Form.id'=>$new_form_id));

                 }
                 $base_fields = $this->get_reference_fields($new_form_id, $base_fields, $reference_field['Field']['id'], $ref_string, $field_name,$base_form,$form_name);

             }


         }

         return $base_fields;

     }
```

==================================
And, a sample result set for the data is:

```
[49-7-6-48] => Doctor - Primary Role
[49-7-6-43] => Doctor - State
[49-7-6-11] => Doctor - Password
[49-7-6-2] => Doctor - Last Name
[49-7-6-10] => Doctor - Username
[49-7-6-28] => Doctor - City
[49-7-6-1] => Doctor - First Name
[49-7-6-24] => Doctor - Middle Initial
[49-7-6-27] => Doctor - Address2
[49-7-6-25] => Doctor - Date of Birth
[49-7-6-47] => Doctor - Phone Number
[49-7-6-26] => Doctor - Address1

[49-7-5-68] => PSG Study - Patient ID Number
[49-7-5-67] => PSG Study - Insurance Provider's Name
[49-7-5-74] => PSG Study - PCP referral required?
[49-7-5-73] => PSG Study - Pre-Authorization Obtained?
[49-7-5-22] => PSG Study - Special Needs
[49-7-5-76] => PSG Study - PCP Phone Number
[49-7-5-69] => PSG Study - Group Number
[49-7-5-70] => PSG Study - Relationship to Insured Member
[49-7-5-71] => PSG Study - Referring Doctor
[49-7-5-75] => PSG Study - If Yes, PCP Name:
[49-7-5-72] => PSG Study - Diagnoses:
[49-7-5-4-48] => Patient - Primary Role
[49-7-5-4-43] => Patient - State
[49-7-5-4-11] => Patient - Password
[49-7-5-4-2] => Patient - Last Name
[49-7-5-4-10] => Patient - Username
[49-7-5-4-28] => Patient - City
[49-7-5-4-1] => Patient - First Name
[49-7-5-4-24] => Patient - Middle Initial
[49-7-5-4-27] => Patient - Address2
[49-7-5-4-25] => Patient - Date of Birth
[49-7-5-4-47] => Patient - Phone Number
[49-7-5-4-26] => Patient - Address1

=========================
```

Can anybody help me figure out an algorithm to properly generate the reference chains?  Please note, it is technically possible for a form to refer to itself.  For example, a Doctor can have a Reference to another Doctor (trainee or supervisor, etc.)

Comment: Just to confirm, are you saying that the initial '$zmr_sections->getSectionList($form_id);' call, against the main form (49 I guess) isn't getting section 5 back, and it should, or that it is getting it back but not including it in the results?  While the loop is maybe a tiny bit inefficient, but I can't see anything obviously wrong in that regard.

Comment: The actual problem is that when it cycles through after doing the reference to doctor, it doesn't drop the id to the doctor field, but instead appends on the patient chain to the doctor field.  The patient chains should not include the 7.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer.  I knew the initialization of the ref_string was the problem. I just couldn't get my head around it.  I added this immediately after the recursive function call

```
  if ($ref_string) {
                        $ref_array = explode('-', $ref_string);
                        array_pop($ref_array);
                        $ref_string = implode('-', $ref_array);
                        $form_name_array = explode('-', $form_name);
                        array_pop($form_name_array);
                        $form_name = implode('-', $form_name_array);
                    }
```